# How to use Rdlc reports in Angular 7

Tags: angular, rdlc, rdl

I have window application in which I have multiple RDLC reports.

Now I am converting window application to Angular 7.

Is there any way to use my existing RDLS reports in Angular 7?

I have read many tutorilas n which they suggest Telerik, Knedo, synfusion and ngx-ssrs-reportviewer but I want to use my existing RDLS reports.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

[ngx-ssrs-reportviewer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-ssrs-reportviewer) is a wrapper around the ReportViewer component, and will let you use your existing RDLS reports if you've published them to the Report Server. However, it has a limitation of only supporting Windows Authentication, so it is really only meant for Intranet use.  The documentation suggests using impersonation to work around this for any Internet application using another authentication approach, but so far I have not been able to figure this out and so my users have to login twice (once to my app with OAuth, then to the Report Server with Windows Auth).